# Bootstrap 3 Slide in Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

I am trying to create a responsive site which has a basic layout in desktop view - Header, Leftnav, main content and right nav, but when the site is viewed on a mobile the initial view is - header and main content but I want to have a menu button, so when clicked the left nav appears on screen over the main content not push. I have been able to achieve this using the responsive bootsrao classes for the left nav to be visible-sm upwards but hidden-xs and I have change the size in the xs class to be 50% width and a specified height and higher z-index than the main -content and having a button with the get element by Id - visibility - visible and vice versa to close the menu.

The problem I have is when i close the menu then increase the size of the browser back to when the left nav would be on screen the area remains blank, i.e. the visibility remains hidden is there anyway I can prevent this from happening?

thanks in advance - see image for example.

strong text![Screens examples][1]

**strong text**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAkrY.png